# Sed inside bash script not working: But it works on command line

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I have tried the following on the command line and they work, but when I place them in a bash script I get an error (see below):

```
sed -e "s/INSERT_ME_HERE/"${ROOT_BUILD_HOME}"/g" ./Doxyfile > ./tmp && mv ./tmp ./Doxyfile
sed -e "s/INSERT_ME_HERE/'${ROOT_BUILD_HOME}'/g" ./Doxyfile > ./tmp && mv ./tmp ./Doxyfile
sed -e "s/INSERT_ME_HERE/`echo ${ROOT_BUILD_HOME}`/g" ./Doxyfile > ./tmp && mv ./tmp ./Doxyfile
```

The error I am getting is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
```

However like I said I am using it from the command line and it works:

```
[mehoggan@hogganz400 Doxygen]$ ROOT_BUILD_HOME=MONKEY; sed -e "s/INSERT_ME_HERE/`echo ${ROOT_BUILD_HOME}`/g" ./Doxyfile | grep MONKEY
INPUT                  = MONKEY
```

Why does it work under one case and not the other?

Also `ROOT_BUILD_HOME` is set, I echo it right before the sed expression within the shell script.

```
echo `date`: "Going to run doxygen on source and move to ${ROOT_BUILD_HOME}";
```

Comment: Just a side note: instead of using a `./tmp` you should give `mktemp` a try for such tasks since it improves the security and robustness of your scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that `ROOT_BUILD_HOME` starts with a `/`, which `sed` is interpreting as ending your replacement-string. Am I right? If so, then try using a different separator:

```
sed -e "s#INSERT_ME_HERE#${ROOT_BUILD_HOME}#g" ./Doxyfile > ./tmp && mv ./tmp ./Doxyfile
```

Comment: That did the trick sir +1 for you. However, can you still explain why it would work on the command line and not in the script?

Comment: @Matthew because it only fails if the value of ROOT_BUILD_HOME contains a slash.  The value in the script does, but "MONKEY" doesn't.

Comment: you can escape it \/. Or create a sed string with replacing / with \/ something like echo /home/|sed -e 's/\//\\\//g'

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

ABC=`echo ${ROOT_BUILD_HOME}`
echo $ABC
sed -e 's/INSERT_ME_HERE/'$ABC'/g' <./Doxyfile > ./tmp && mv ./tmp ./Doxyfile
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hope this one will give you more insight why it did work on script :)

Comment: I do not get what you need the `ABC` variable for. What would be different if you substituted the first two lines with `echo ${ROOT_BUILD_HOME}` or even `echo $ROOT_BUILD_HOME`?